# Probability of picking red marker.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

If $20$ markers are drawn from a large number of markers in which 10% of them are red markers.  What is the probability that number of red markers drawn exceeds the expectation of number of red markers ? (Use poisson distribution).

---

Here mean or expectation is calculated as $20\cdot\frac{1}{10} = 2$.

Now

$$P(X > 2)  = 1 - \Big( P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2)\Big) 
                          = 1 - 5e^{-2}\approx0.323$$

Here I don't understand how can we pick more than $2$ markers if only $10%$ of $20$ markers $2$ are red. I think it should be $0$ as we only have $2$ red markers and we can't pick more than $2$ red markers.

Comment: Not following your question.  Nobody said that your sample is $10\%$ red.  All we know is that the huge pool of markers is $10\%$ red.  It is perfectly possibly that you draw $20$ red ones (though that isn't terribly probable).

Comment: Not $10$ percent of the $20$ drawn markers is said to be red, but $10$ percent of the total (large) number of markers. Then it is still possible (not probable though) to draw even $20$ red ones.

Comment: Side note:  I'm not sure why the poisson distribution is specified.  It's not difficult to use the binomial distribution (which is exact).  I suppose it's just part of an exercise in learning to use the poisson distribution, in which case I would recommend doing it both ways to compare the approximation to the true result.

Comment: In the formula of mean for poisson which is np, what exactly is n ? Is it the number of trials ?

Comment: Yes it is the number of trials.  This is another reason why you should do it exactly, via the binomial distribution.  If the answers are far apart that ought to suggest that an error was made.